# how can i get facebook like's details of a page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page on facebook. And i want to get all information about likes of that page even Person's name as well who likes that page. I am admin of that page.

I have tried with this:

https://graph.facebook.com/230138545131/likes?access_token=XXX

but it is giving empty data.

facebook provides only object(i.e. post, photo etc.) likes, but i want to get page's likes information.

can anybody help me...

Comment: Can't you just view the list of people who like it from the page? Please be more descriptive of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that with pages, I think you need to use an app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do that by setting an app and using facebook FQL. A query for get the link stats could be like:

```
SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, click_count
FROM link_stat
WHERE url = '$myURL'
```

Find more infos at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score -1):

You could use what's called HTML Scraping where your php server makes a http request to get the facebook page url, and parse the string returned to get the 6 people who like it. Simply call this in a loop to get more than 6. Add to a database with a UNIQUE constraint on the Persons id or name column.